# How could a Python "print" statement take 100 milliseconds to execute on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Python program that I run on a Windows 7 computer as well as a Raspberry Pi running Linux. On the Windows machine, the main loop of the program takes on average about 4 milliseconds to run. On the Raspberry Pi, it takes on average about 100 milliseconds to run.

I tracked the time difference down to one line of code:

```
print(newData.decode('utf-8'))
```

If I take out that line of code (which was only in there for debugging purposes anyway), the program runs just as quickly on the Raspberry Pi.

I cannot figure out how this one line of code can take so much longer on the Raspberry Pi than on the Windows machine. Any ideas?

EDITED TO ADD:

Thanks for the various comments. Just to clarify, the line of code listed above was not needed in the program, so I can delete it with no ill effect. But even though I realize that the Raspberry Pi is slower than my desktop computer, one simple line of code would not normally take 100 milliseconds to execute on any computer.

The Raspberry Pi may be slow, but it still runs at 700 MHz, which means 70,000,000 clock ticks in that amount of time. I cannot figure out what could possibly be happening to make the 0.1 second difference since the code on both machines is almost exactly the same.

Comment: It's probably not the `print` but the `decode`. Which class does the class instance `newData` to?

Comment: What happens if you redirect output to a file instead? When writing to a console there can be a big difference depending on the type of connection (ssh, serial, ...). What kind of terminal are you using?

Comment: Thanks, Marcus Rickert, that does make sense that it is the `decode` part of the command. `newData` contains up to 40 characters received on a TCP socket.

Comment: Consider the very different terminals: the *primitive* Windows terminal and the much less so Linux one.

Comment: mata, I haven't tried redirecting output to a file. Since the print command was in there just for debugging, I could take it out and see it was the problem. I'm not using a terminal. I'm just writing to the console that appears in `idle3` on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Be aware, that on RaspberryPi you have much slower processor and much slower disk drive than on your notebook. Any output to a console is slowing things down (everywhere), and writing data to a file can be slow too. I would recommend dumping the output to `/dev/null`.